# jspm.io is searching remotely for my local module

Tags: angular, jspm, systemjs

I have a very strange issue. The code below works fine.
However if I change the angular script, to my local one.
All of a sudden, when

```
System.import('components/app/app')
```

runs, **it searches on jspm.io for the script, instead of my local**. Why is this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jspm.io/system@@0.16.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.22/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.traceurOptions = {
          annotations: true,
          memberVariables: true,
          typeAssertions: false,
          types: true
        };
        System.config({
          baseURL: '/'
        });
    </script>
    <script src="/javascripts/libs/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/libs/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    @html.block('primary', function(model){
      <app></app>
    })
    <script>
      System.import('components/app/app').then(function(module) {
        // uncomment for debugging.
        // zone = zone.fork(Zone.longStackTraceZone);
        //return module.main();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot explain why, but I had this same problem where my local js file was attempting to be retrieved from jspm.io when I was using alpha.27 angular2.js, but it did not happen which I switched to angular2.dev.js.

Comment: I asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120244/angular2-system-js-make-all-files-load-locally