# Angular2 + System.js - make all files load locally

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

I'm making Angular2 app, and the main HTML is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>App</title>
        <script src="./lib/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/system.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <app></app>
        <script src="./js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

My goal is to make all files load locally. So - when I put those three files in the lib folder - I saw in the network inspector that it can't load "es6-modules-loader@0.16.6.js" from there, so I downloaded that file from Internet and put it in the "lib" folder. Then all worked fine :)

BUT:

Today the network connections stopped for a while, and I couldn't run the project, cause it actually loaded two more files from the net:

```
https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur@0.0.87.js
https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur@0.0.87/traceur.js
```

I see them defined at the end of system.js.

So my question is: How can I make everything loads from the local filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

This is my set up, I hope it works for you

I installed all this packages through `npm`.

```
<script src="node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>

<!-- alpha35 -->
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

With simply this, systemjs will not be able to find any of the angular2 files, so you have to add [paths](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#paths) in System.config to tell to systemjs where angular2's files are.

```
System.config({
    traceurOptions: {
        annotations: true,
        types: true,
        memberVariables: true
    },
    paths: {
       'angular2/*' : 'node_modules/angular2/*'
    },
    defaultJSExtensions: true // or you specify the .js
});
```

This is my set up, not necessarily the best one, but it works for me.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: i'll check it & will let U know :) ... Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: You not solve problem. We ask - how to load definitions from BUDLES located in local folder without npm. If you are not using paths, map - it work, but if you set up one of this options - local definitions clear